# MATLAB simple code didn't work - connect matlab to Mysql Using a ODBC Driver

Tags: sql, matlab

i installed mysql server 5.6 , and Mysql connector ODBC , and tested in matlab with database explorer and worked fine as you can see in the image :

[image]

how ever when i tried to connect it by a script didn't work , however i did the exact code in the documentation here :

> Connect to MySQL using the native ODBC connection command line.

with the correct informations of course ,  data source name and the correct username and password

```
conn = database.ODBCConnection('Zernike','root','0xen');
```

but i keep getting this code :

```
>> database

ans =

       Instance: []
       UserName: []
         Driver: []
            URL: []
    Constructor: []
        Message: 'Incorrect number of input arguments. Check documentation for usage'
         Handle: []
        TimeOut: []
     AutoCommit: []
           Type: []
```

and there is another screenshot :

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/diPoj.jpg

Comment: Can you give details on your matlab version? Also use the 'which' command to check the path of database.ODBCConnection

Comment: my matlab : r2015 (8.5.0.197613) 32bit 
and 
which result : 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\MATLAB Production Server\R2015a\toolbox\database\database\+database\@ODBCConnection\ODBCConnection.m  % database.ODBCConnection constructor`

Comment: It looks to me instead of the builtin functions some other are called. Can you check http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.codetools.requiredfilesandproducts.html and see if there is anything in the list that doesn't look stock?

Comment: mmmm i'm a bit newbie in matlab , is my code and method correct ?

Comment: Your code looks exactly as shown in the examples of the help. So it is correct. The error message is very common when MATLAB runs a custom function instead of the builtin ones. So that would be my bet. Finding it is unfortunately not easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i get the matlab 2014 x64 the code worked proprly , it seems the probleme in my r2015 x84 version